# How to monitor element changes on a UL element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to monitor a UL element for the changes in child elements such as li added or removed etc. The UL is used to display tabs in the screen where each li will be a separate tab. I don't have control to modify the tab script to call my own functions in my script file when the tabs are changed.

I have to support IE browser mainly for this and have to do it using pure JavaScript.

Comment: Right, so what have you looked into/tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way i know for this to be possible would be like this. I cannot say that this is a very good way to do it though.

```
var onchange = function(element, callback) {
    var HTML = element.innerHTML;
    window.setInterval(function() {
        var newHTML = element.innerHTML;
        if(HTML !== newHTML) {
            HTML = newHTML;
            callback(element);
        }
    });
}
```

This will monitor the element and check the `innerHTML` if it has changed it will call your callback function.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qmB97/**

Usage:

```
onchange(HTMLElement, function() {
   alert('change');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try with UL element.

Comment: Does onchange fire only once for all the changes that I have made? http://jsfiddle.net/qmB97/12/

Comment: It fires every time the element is changed, but in that example all of the changes are made at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Connor.. I will go with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

IE11 should support [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Thank you fusio, but we are using an older version of IE.