# How to show content when attribute is active

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem:

I have a slideshow containing 3 slides changing after 10 seconds which is generated by plugin so i don't have access to the html file.

```
<ul>
  <li data-index="rs-101">
  <li data-index="rs-102">
  <li data-index="rs-103">
</ul>

 <div class="content1">
   content1
 </div>
 <div class="content2">
   content2
 </div>
 <div class="content3">
   content3
 </div>
```

This slider is on the top of the screen and now I want to change the bottom of the screen according to the slides:

if rs-101 is selected: do this
if rs-102 is selected: do that
..

I found this which is not working:

```
function Content1(){ 
    if ( $('html').attr('data-index') == 'rs-101' ) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("content1"); 
    x1.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x1.style.display = "none";
} 
function Content2(){ 
    if ( $('html').attr('data-index') == 'rs-102' ) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("content1"); 
    x2.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x2.style.display = "none";
} 
function Content3(){ 
    if ( $('html').attr('data-index') == 'rs-103' ) {
    var x3 = document.getElementById("content1"); 
    x3.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x3.style.display = "none";
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: You have defined functions however there is no code actively executing these functions? I would attempt to have a onChange event that calls a single function which grabs the data-index and completes the code as required. Could you explain how the <li> gets populated? Is there only ever 1 <li> visible etc.

Comment: please check here: http://packageonly.tk/test

Comment: You know, i want to connect the content to the slides..so whenever slide changes, the content should change...So there shouldnt be any execution or onChange event because its already being changed..

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, I would assume the plugin still needs to be modifying something in the HTML to cause the visual change, that change is what you need to hook in to. You can then dynamically adjust the page content to match what is being display.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311216/9785689 to monitor the list for changes, when it detects a change call a single function changeContent(). If this doesn't work then you need to have a way to listen for the automated changes from the plugin (I would check with the author or the plugin).

```
function ChangeContent(){
  var data = $('html').attr('data-index');
  if ( data == 'rs-101' ) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("content1"); 
    x1.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x1.style.display = "none";
  } 

  if ( data == 'rs-102' ) {
    var x1 = document.getElementById("content1"); 
    x2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     x2.style.display = "none";
  }

  if ( data == 'rs-103' ) {
    var x3 = document.getElementById("content1"); 
    x3.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x3.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```